# Why am I failing to send requests to Tweepy (Twitter's API) failing all of a sudden?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a script that writes content to my Twitter accounts using Twitter's API, Tweepy. All of a sudden, the script has come into trouble sending requests to Tweepy.

**Nothing in my script has changed** so I am assuming this is a problem on Twitter's end. My internet connect is fine as I am able to connect to other websites' APIs.

When trying to do something with Tweepy, I received different error messages like:

*Failed to send request: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:661)*
and 
*Failed to send request: ('The write operation timed out',)*

**Are other people running into this problem too?** If so, I will safely assume it is a problem on Twitter's end like I believe it to be.

Comment: Did anything on the server change?

Comment: I'm able to use Tweepy. Maybe something to do with your account? Is twitter blocked from your network?

Comment: I tried the script out again today and received this error message: Failed to send request: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /1.1/users/show.json?id=838502954483187716 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x034799F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))

Comment: @HazardousGlitch This makes me think that it is a connection error; however, my connection seems to be fine as I am able to load HD video without any problems. Nothing on my server/network changed that I know of. Any ideas on how I can go about fixing this???

Comment: @HarshithBolar Twitter isn't blocked from my network and my accounts seem to be fine